# Matlab Functions - How do I access structures with string-input?

Tags: string, matlab, function

If I have a function like this:

```
function [ out ] = call(a)
out = s.a
end
```

How can I get it to access the structure s.hello with call('hello') or someting like this?

side question: Is it also possible to access a Variable "hello" with such a function?

Thanks in advance, you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use dynamic structure access like so:

```
s.(a)
```

Learn more at the [Mathworks website!](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Also, if we look at your example function, I notice you're not passing in the structure as an argument, maybe it's global, but here an example of this technique using your function as a framework:

```
function out = call(s,a)
  out = s.(a);
end
```

Then to use the function, I try:

```
>> s = struct('hello',42)

s = 

    hello: 42

>> call(s,'hello')

ans =

    42
```

Works great with no recursion limit!  If you're still getting a recursive function, try adding more of your code to the question, we'll get to the bottom of this!

HTH

Comment: I tried that already, but it gives me errors, one was like this:
??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

I simply used the structure like 
a.hello
a.ciao

And called it with the above state function
test = call('hello')

Comment: @Lasse, see my updates here, hope this is helpful!

Comment: okay, seems it had problems with the structure-name, which i also have to feed the function, right?